# Seventh chords and the key a song is written in

Tags: chord-progressions, chord-theory

I'm a self-learner and understands how major and minor  chords are made up and how extended chords are build from these, like *sus2*, *sus4* and 7th chords (if I'm correct, these are just embellishments of those major and minor chords). I also know about chords within a specific key and know that songs can be written in a specific key or written in such a way that it doesn't fit into a single key.

What beats me is seventh chords. Let's take the song, *Black* by Pearl Jam. The verse and intro has a simple progression, E7-A. They do sometimes when playing this live, change the *A* to an *Asus2* chord (which is just an embellished A chord) every other time. If I'm correct here, the verse is written in the key of A because a dominant 7th is build from the dominant chord within a given key. In this example, E is the dominant chord in the key of A. That is how I understand it. So my progression would be V-I if I want to transpose this to another key.

The rest of the song is written in *Em* as there are other two progression in the song which consist of C-Em and D-C-Em

Now, if the progression in the verse was Emaj7-A, that would mean the song is written in the key of E because the 7th here which is added to the *E* is a true 7th degree of the E major scale. This would therefor be a I-IV chord progression.

My question is, is this info correct, and if not, why?. Also, this would mean that, if a progression have two different dominant 7th's, then that progression aren't written in one specific key but is basically a mix between diffirent keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as transposing is concerned, it doesn't matter which standpoint you take, as long as you use the same idea in a new key. It'll all translate properly.

The E7/Emaj7 debate doesn't add up to much, either. In key E, there are often Emaj7s, but before going to IV (A), there could well be E dominant 7 (E7). Yes, that chord could be construed as "not being in E, but A instead", but it usually doesn't mean the tune is then modulating/changing key to A.There are no Emaj7s to be heard, though.

The tune *sounds* as if it's in A, as that's where the cadences feel at rest. So where's the C part? Parallel keys is the answer here. It's common to use chords from both the major and minor keys. So in A minor, C major appears.There's also the propensity tu use E and/or Em. By the way, the sequence is difficult to tell - C>Em or C>E. At least at one point the bassist seems to think it goes to E...

Comment: Shy downvoters again? Need to know what's so awful please!

Answer (score 0):

You can't work out where the tonal centre of a song is 'by numbers'.  At least, not in the simplistic way of trying to make all the chords fit into one scale.  A prime example of this is a simple blues.   A7, D7, A7, E7, D7, A7.   That's definitely a 'blues in A'.  You have to embrace a system that can cope with the G nat and C nat.  And that can let a dominant 7th shape chord not BE a dominant.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a listen and a look at the music sheet, and I suspect A really is where the tune lives. You'll note that, on the transition to the chorus, there is a distinct shift. A full-fledged modulation? Perhaps not, but certainly a change of mode.

So, consider A as the tonic - what do you have? V - I, etc. going to IV - ♭III - v, which makes a quite logical shift to Dorian using IV as a pivot. ♭III - v confirms the mode shift. Sharp the third in v, and we're back in the verse with a leading tone to I. This all goes along with the fade-out ending (which ends on repeated D - C) - the whole chorus leaves us hanging.

So let's summarise the evidence: we have a standard dominant-tonic succession in the major; we move to the other strong tonal degree IV, and use it as a common chord pivot to Dorian mode; we hear the three chords that define that mode as well as it can be defined without direct reference to the tonic (IV - ♭III - v), which is in keeping with the endless yearning the song is trying to project; and the song ends without resolution, which is also in keeping with the mood.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the chords I'm looking at in the song it's written in Emaj.

These are the chords it's using E, Asus2, A, C, Em, D.

1. Emaj is I
2. Asus2 is IV
3. A is IV
4. C is bVI (flat six major)- chord chromaticism
5. Em is i (key change) - chord chromaticism
6. D is bVII (flat seven major) - chord chromaticism

that is looking at it from Emaj

Now you could look at the from a key change point of view of Em

1. the C would be a VI
2. D is a VII